# Unity Change UI Z-Axis

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating an Archery, Platformer, Shooting game named "ArcheryRun" with a small team. We have a powerbar (shown in orange) which increases as you hold down the "Left Mouse Button". However since its a UI element it is static in a position.

I would like it to appear above the player when they change their z-axis as Ive done with the Arrow Image by using a 2D Sprite object. However I can't seem how to change the z-axis of a UI Image relative to the player or use a Game Object which allows a fill option.

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

[Change Orange Powerbar to Follow Player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHvoK.png)

Comment: You question is hard to understand even with the image. Try to re-phrase it. What's wrong with your UI? What do you want it to do?

Comment: @Programmer I believe they are trying to make their UI powerbar follow on top of the player object as it moves around the screen. I'm thinking that they may need to utilize a WorldSpace canvas or use a 3D texture. A clarification would be beneficial

Comment: Thats exactly right, sorry for the bad phrasing of the question, didn't know how to word it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we understand your question, this should work:

This method gives you screen canvas position from world position:

```
    public static Vector3 GetScreenPositionFromWorldPosition(Vector3 targetPosition)
    {
        Vector3 screenPos;    
        screenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(targetPosition);
        return new Vector3 (screenPos.x, screenPos.y, 0f);
    }
```

Then you need a script on top of power bar, lets say like this:

```
public class PowerBar : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Transform target;
    RectTransform _rectTransform;

    void Awake ()
    {
        _rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform> ();
    }

    public void updatePosition()
    {
        Vector3 pos = YourStaticClassWith.GetScreenPositionFromWorldPosition (target.position);
        Vector2 rpos = pos;
        _rectTransform.anchoredPosition3D = rpos + Vector2.up * 100f; // 100f is value of how many pixels above the target that UI element should apear
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        updatePosition ();
    }
}
```

The `target` is basicly `transform` of your player object.

The `100f` value represents pixels above the target.

Comment: Thanks so much, it works as intended now. The problem was that the powerbar canvas had to be in world space.